# Resolving promises on filter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a filter and I can't get it to resolve the promise. It is using a model called 'patient' that hasMany 'addresses' and I want to filter out the address that has an addressType of 'Primary'. The filter seems to be working but only will return a promise. Thank you in advance for the help.

#### Patient controller

```
App.PatientController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  primaryAddress: Em.computed 'model.@each.addresses', ->
    @get('model.addresses').then (addresses)->
      addresses.filterBy 'addressType', 'Primary'
```

[image]

#### Solution (Thanks to @GJK)

```
  primaryAddress: Em.computed 'model.addresses.@each', ->
    @get('model.addresses').filterBy('addressType', 'Primary').get('firstObject')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious issue that I can see is that you're not watching the `@each` property of the addresses. Your property depends on `model.@each.addresses`, which means that your `model` is an array, and you're observing the `addresses` property on each item in that array. But you're not observing the content of the `addresses` array, just the array itself.

It seems to me that you should use `model.addresses.@each` as your dependent property. This will observe all addresses on a single model, including observing the contents of the `addresses` array (which updates when the promise resolves).

EDIT: Also, I didn't quite read far enough apparently. You shouldn't be calling `then` on the promise. Treat it as if it's already resolved, and it'll be updated when it does resolve. So use this instead:

```
App.PatientController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  primaryAddress: Em.computed 'model.addresses.@each', ->
    @get('model.addresses').filterBy 'addressType', 'Primary'
```

The first time this property comptues, the promise will be unresolved so the filter won't return anything. But when the promise resolves, the property will update and the filter will work like you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed it and am getting the same promise back but that makes great sense as to why it needed to change.

Comment: I noticed one other issue that I didn't see before. I posted an update that should work.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Finally got it working. I had to pull the first object off of the array but everything else was thanks to you. I'll add the solution to my question.